# Grabbing sniffed packet data

Tags: network-monitoring

So I have a Fiddler2 capture. In the capture, there was a file that was downloaded, file.dat. I am trying to extract the downloaded file from the capture. I can't seem to find any way to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

Right click on session, go to Save -> Save Response -> Response Body